# Why is a comma not used in two of these sentences?

Tags: commas

I came across the following paragraph in a book and am a bit confused about the punctuation. I would be grateful if you could explain it to me.

> ***Thus if it comes to a child while he is looking at a far off hillside he at once thinks 'if only I were there'***; if it comes when he is remembering some event in the past, he thinks 'if only I could go back to those days'. If it comes (a little later) while he is reading a 'romantic' tale or poem of 'perilous seas and faerie lands forlorn', he thinks he is wishing that such places really existed and that he could reach them. ***If it comes (later still) in a context with erotic suggestions he believes he is desiring the perfect beloved.*** If he falls upon literature (like Maeterlinck or the early Yeats) which treats of spirits and the like with some show of serious belief, he may think he is hankering for real magic and occultism. When it darts out upon him from his studies in history or science, he may confuse it with the intellectual craving for knowledge.

Why is a comma not used for the two sentences below?

> - Thus if it comes to a child while he is looking at a far off hillside he at once thinks 'if only I were there'
> - If it comes (later still) in a context with erotic suggestions he believes he is desiring the perfect beloved.

Should they not read:

> - Thus if it comes to a child while he is looking at a far off hillside, he at once thinks 'if only I were there'.
> - If it comes (later still) in a context with erotic suggestions, he believes he is desiring the perfect beloved.

Comment: IMO you can write those sentences with or without the commas and it still makes sense.

Comment: In modern English the common convention would be to put a comma after the subordinate clause. I get the impression that this text is not so recent.

Comment: @SConroy  "I get the impression that this text is not so recent." You are correct. The text was written in 1933.

Comment: By the way is that "he" a typo? Should it be "it" or is it deliberately raunchy?

Comment: That was a typo

Comment: Please tell us what book and if it is a translation. That should be included in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That a [comma is obligatory](https://writingcommons.org/open-text/collaboration/96-common-comments/punctuation-/commas/358-use-commas-after-introductory-subordinate-clauses) after an introductory subordinate clause should be uncontroversial, especially since this author follows the rule four times in the cited passage but for some reason ignores it twice.

This is not some arbitrary convention, but often necessary to signal where the next clause begins. For instance, in your second example, readers without the aid of a separating comma might expect something like

> If it comes (later still) in a context with erotic suggestions he believes come from the deepest part of his subconscious...

and then be forced to reparse the sentence: the comma signals the beginning of the next clause.

---